# Jmeter Test Summary out put showing for individual Thread Group though the same functionalities passed in each

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I have used BZM Cuncurrency Users Thread Group.
I have noticed the Jmeter Test Summary out put showing for individual Thread Group though the same functionalities passed in each thread.
50 Concurrency users with total 5 thread group, each thread group got same values were passed but results shows individually has showed in the screenshot (For ThreadGroup-1, ThreadGroup-2.......).
but sometimes it's given singe report though there is 5 or 10 ThreadGroups

Looking forward your help get resolution on the same
[image]

Correct output:
[image]

Incorrect Out put as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Never run your load test using JMeter GUI**, GUI mode is for tests development and/or debugging, once you finish test development and verify that it works fine with 1-2 virtual users/iterations using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request/response details you [should be running JMeter tests using command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/test/results.jtl
```

Also don't forget to disable or even delete all the Listeners from your test plan, the [Listeners don't add any value and only consume resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/).

Once your test is finished you can open the `results.jtl` file with the Listener of your choice or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response, let me try the above and get back to you.